# toolStripBox1.Items.Add(toolStripTextBox.Text); Error at items

Tags: c#, winforms

I know the title might be confusing but I will give a better-detailed explanation.

I am currently trying to make a web browser. I am stuck with this issue and still can't find a fix for it.
And my error is at toolStripTextBox.Items<--- HERE it turns red squiggly underline
It gives me...

> "'ToolStripTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'ToolStripTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

help is appreciated

```
private void goToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  ((WebBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
  if (!toolStripTextBox1.Items.Contains(toolStripTextBox1.Text))
  {
    toolStripTextBox1.Items.Add(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am 95% sure you meant to use `goToolStripMenuItem.Items`.

Comment: @mjwills I just tried that, it is still giving me the error at the .Items, not toolStripTextBox1

Comment: In that case you will need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why would a TextBox have an Items collection, or a collection of anything?  It's a TextBox.  Did you mean goToolStripMenuItem with the DropDownItems collection?  That would make a little more sense.

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the titles here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your description:
 toolStripTextBox1 is a textbox and thus you cannot add items like a list or collection .

```
toolStripTextBox1.Items.Add(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
```

For this code to work,toolStripTextBox1 should be toolstrip  .You can add items 
like this

```
toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working what you suggested. (sorry for VERY late reply)

Comment: It also is named toolStripTextBox1 (is what I am trying to get) and is says "toolStrip1" does not exist in this current context.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing my toolStripTextBox1 to a ComboBox.